# Java Syntax Error

Tags: java, syntax, syntax-error

What is wrong with my code? I have an error concerning the scanner part of it.
I have to add "more details be4 I can post this question, so this is it.

```
import java.util.Scanner
class rectangle
{
  double width;
  double length;
  double findArea(double a, double b)
  {
    width=a;
    length=b;
    return a*b;
  }
}
public class area
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    {
      System.out.println("Enter the dimensions of the square.");
      Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
    {
      rectangle objrect = new rectangle();
      System.out.println(objrect.findArea(x, y));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Always copy/paste error & exception output. 2) Please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your' & 'please'.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing two `Scanner` objects to a method `findArea` that expects two `double` values; that won't work.  You should have one `Scanner` object, with which you should be able to obtain `double` values that you can pass in to the `findArea` method.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the x and y value input line with follows:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
double x = s.nextDouble();
double y = s.nextDouble();
```

Now call the method finaArea as follows:

```
objrect.findArea(x, y)
```